# Html.fromHtml not showing image after converting

Tags: android, html, android-intent

I am changing my html text to string and send to email intent in android. here is my code :

```
   Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                            "mailto",(mail_name), null));
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mail_subject);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<img src=\\\"http://i.imgur.com/9nyKcwl.jpg\\\" width=\\\"381\\\"><br>", new ImageGetter(), null));
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

In email section i am not getting any image.

Answer (score 0):

`\\\"` escapes the backslash and `"` to `\"` which does not seem correct. Use `"<img src=\"http://i.imgur.com/9nyKcwl.jpg\" width=\"381\"><br>"`